# Kronecker Product Reformulation

Tags: kronecker-product

I have 2 questions concerning the reformulation of a Kronecker products where i kind of got stuck.
Firstly assume the matrix $V\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$ is defined as
$$
        V=\left[\begin{matrix}
        v_0 \\
        \vdots\\
        v_{N-1}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$
with $v_i \in\mathbb{C}^{1\times M}, i\in\{0, \ldots,N-1\}$. Furthermore let vector $\Gamma\in\mathbb{C}^{MP \times 1}$ and we want to calculate
$$
    B=\left[\begin{matrix}
        I_P\otimes v_0 \\
        \vdots\\
        I_P \otimes v_{N-1}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\Gamma
$$
Is it possible to reformulate B in terms of $V$?.

Using this I actually want to calculate the following product
$$
C = D^H(I_N\otimes f)\left[\begin{matrix}
        I_P\otimes v_0 \\
        \vdots\\
        I_P \otimes v_{N-1}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\Gamma
$$
with $D\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times L}$ and $L\leq N$ and $f\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times P}$. Can we reformulate $C$ in such a way that $D^H$ is multiplied with $V$ to obtain a matrix $V'=D^HV$ to obtain something like
$$
C = (I_?\otimes f)\left[\begin{matrix}
        I_?\otimes v'_0 \\
        \vdots\\
        I_? \otimes v'_{N-1}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\Gamma
$$
so the matrix D is directly applied? Could you also maybe provide some resources references where I can look into further detail? It would really help me!

Thank you a lot!